# Is User.password supposed to be nil in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am debugging a problem in my Rails 6 app using Devise 4.7.1. I am unable to login with email/password. (I can reset password, and login that way, or use Facebook login.)

The password appears to be getting added to the `users.encrypted_password` column correctly. It's encrypted, so I can't tell for sure, but the column is not empty when I look at it using the mysql client.

I noticed that when I run `rails c` to debug, Here's what I get:

```
2.5.8 :048 > User.last.password
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Is `User.password` supposed to be `nil`, or is that the expected behavior? I'm trying to understand if this is the source of my problem, or if it's a red herring.

If there's some way I can debug this in the rails console, so I can be sure the value is set correctly, that would be helpful. e.g. `User.last.password == some_hash_method('password')`.

`User.encrypted_password` does return a value:

```
2.5.8 :049 > User.last.encrypted_password
  User Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => "$2a$11$pMGOZ/a5YG3Z/QHQ3WZBRO0HpqOGpCRuWyxb6X___SNIPPED___"
```

Answer (score 3):

`user.password` is an `attr_accessor` in devise, it will always be nil when you initiate a user after querying it from the db. The password is hashed and stored in the `encrypted_password` field after hashing by devise.

Passwords are never stored directly on the db as this is a serious security threat.
For the purposes of debugging, you can create a new devise controller and print the password when you receive it from the new session form. Do not do this in production though as this is a major security threat

Comment: Thanks for explaining that it is supposed to be nil. Do you happen to know *why* it's designed that way? I spent ages debugging thinking that the password wasn't getting saved, before I realized that it was in fact in the DB. I understand that you never want to have readable passwords stored. However I am curious why have an `attr_accessor` that always returns nil? (In my case, the password can be unset, because the user could register via omniauth.)

Comment: @antun Thats true. I don't remember exactly how it works with `omniauth`. The password doesn't always return `nil`. If you instantiate a user from the db by doing `u = User.first` and set the password by doing `u.password = "password"`, the next time you do `u.password`, you'll get `"password"` back. One you do `u.save`, the password is validated according to the rules, hashed and saved in the `u.encrypted_password` field and removed from the accessor.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug this in the rails console, @user is a User Object and "password" is plain text password which user has set. It gives you boolean true if password is valid else false.

```
@user.valid_password?("password")
```